# Error in declaring template

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I'm making my first use of c++ template to declare a simple returning for a vector of ints, int64_t, floats or doubles its mean and standard deviation in a pair of doubles objects.

I've been trying to copy the models I found on the internet and started with:

```
template<typename Type>
pair<double,double> mean_std(vector<Type>::iterator the_beg, vector<Type>::iterator the_end){
// rest of my function
```

but this already returns me the errors:

```
 template declaration of ‘std::pair<double, double> mean_std’
 code.cpp:22:53: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘the_beg’
 code.cpp:22:85: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘the_end’
```

when compiling.

Is it because of some subtlety in using templates with vector (or their iterators)?

Comment: Use the `typename` keyword with both parameters (right before `vector`). Also, are you `using namespace std`? I would actually recommend against doing this, but the way you've written the code requires it.

Comment: `typename vector<Type>::iterator the_beg` welcome to templates.

Comment: What happens if the average etc is not representable for Type by a double? Eg complex number (don't know how that works with averages, not a maths pro). Also you should create two different functions to calculation mean and standard deviation.

Comment: @NeilKirk : Many thanks!! Indeed it works after adding typename. Answering your next points: I have no intentions, for now, on using it on complex numbers, and I prefer extracting the mean and std in one pass, as I always need both of them.

Comment: @dlf: Yes I declared `using namespace std;` above these lines of code, indeed otherwise I would have `std::vector`. I know there are points for which it can become a problem but so far so good in my case (I mean no conflicts between names in the std and elsewhere)

Comment: @Neil: By the way, is there a way to avoid the redundancy of specifying the type of the vector I'm feeding my function? To let it read it from the object itself? I mean without getting into dozens of lines of code?

Comment: `template<typename ITR> pair<double,double> mean_std(ITR the_beg, ITR the_end)` Use `typename ITR::value_type` to get the stored type.

Comment: @NeilKirk Thank you very much, bookmarking this ;)